# Partial match strings to drop df columns in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have the code below.

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = 0))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
x <- c("A1.1gender", "A1.2gender", "A1.3gender", "A1.4gender", "A1.5gender", "A1.6gender")
y <- c("A1.1age", "A1.2age", "A1.3age")
colnames(df1) <- x
colnames(df2) <- y
```

How can I drop the A1.4, A1.5, and A1.6 columns from df1 by using partial string match from df2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses `gsub`and backreference in `\\1` to recall the critical number following `A1.` that the column names of `df1`and `df2`have in common (namely "1", "2", and "3") as well as `%in%` to match these columns; `df1`is then subsetted on these matching column names:

```
df1[,  gsub("A1\\.(\\d).*", "\\1", colnames(df1)) %in% gsub("A1\\.(\\d).*", "\\1", colnames(df2))]
[1] A1.1gender A1.2gender A1.3gender
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes!! Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's been a pleasure!